# MathJax colored in Jekyll site

Tags: jekyll, mathjax

I just added MathJax support to my Jekyll Bootsrap site by adding `type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>`
 to `header.html`. It works, but everything rendered as MathJax *except* numbers takes the color of numbers in my code highlighting.

I have tried adding `.highlight` in front of each line in my `_syntax.scss` per [this suggestion](http://blog.jincan.info/web/2013/05/04/set-up-a-blog-using-jekyll-bootstrap/) to no avail; even deleting all of the color lines in `_syntax.scss` doesn't change the MathJax coloring; neither does setting `highlighter: null` in `_config.yml`. Any ideas?

Comment: And can we see your code somewhere ?

Comment: Some CSS from your page is affecting the MathJax output.  Use the developer tools to inspect the DOM and select some MathJax output.  Look through the styles in effect for that element and see what is applying the color.  That might give you a clue for what CSS to use to override that.  You might try something like `.MathJax * {color: inherit}`, but without knowing the actual CSS rule that is causing the problem, it is hard to tell you what will work.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was absolute URLs. Adding the `.highlight` prefix did do the trick, my local build just didn't pick it up because the styling was done by the CSS file on my deployed site. Thanks for pointing me to it, Davide.